# how to show database errors like constraints or any in web application as an alert or an error page

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

I have a page where am adding an employee into a table. In table i have set a composite key. If i insert same record through my application it throws error "**HTTP Status 500 - PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ROLE(EMP_NUM,ROLE,STATUS)VALUES (?,?,'LOGGEDIN')]; ORA-00001: unique constraint (EMPLOYEE_ROLE_PK) violated**"

My JSP page:
     
                            Add New User Details

```
                         <%
                            System.out.println("your selected Emp_Num from script :"+request.getParameter("enum")+" "+request.getParameter("ename"));
                            String eNum=request.getParameter("enum");
                            String eName=request.getParameter("ename");
                            if(eNum!=null){
                                System.out.println("your selected Emp_Num inside servlet:"+eNum);
                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empList1 = UserJdbcGenericDao.empNameDetails_AA(eNum);
                                System.out.println("Size (servlet): "+empList1.size());
                                for (int i=0;i<empList1.size();i++) {%>
                                    <tr><td><label for="empNum">Employee Number:</label></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <select id="empNum" name="empNum">
                                    <option  value="<%=empList1.get(i).get("3")%>" selected="selected"><%=empList1.get(i).get("3")%></option>
                                    <%
                                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empList = UserJdbcGenericDao.empNumDetails_AA();
                                        for (int j=0;j<empList.size();j++) {
                                    %> 

                                    </select>
                                    <% }%>
                                    </td>

                                    <td><label for="empName">Employee Name:</label></td>                            
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="empName" name="empName" size="1">
                                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Emp_Num:</option>
                                            <option value="" selected="selected"><%=empList1.get(i).get("0")+empList1.get(i).get("1")+empList1.get(i).get("2")%></option>       
                                        </select>
                               <% }
                            }else if(eName!=null){%>
                            </td><% 

                                System.out.println("your selected Emp_Num inside servlet:"+eName);
                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empList1 = UserJdbcGenericDao.empNameDetails_AAname(eName);
                                System.out.println("Size (servlet): "+empList1.size());
                                for (int i=0;i<empList1.size();i++) {%>

                                    <tr><td><label for="empNum">Employee Number:</label></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <select id="empNum" name="empNum" onchange="selectEmpNum()">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected"><%=empList1.get(i).get("3")%></option>
                                    <%
                                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empList = UserJdbcGenericDao.empNumDetails_AA();
                                        for (int j=0;j<empList.size();j++) {
                                    %> 

                                    </select>
                                    <% }%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><label for="empFName">Employee Name:</label></td>                           
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="empFName" name="empFName" size="1">
                                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Emp_Num:</option>
                                            <option value="" selected="selected"><%=empList1.get(i).get("0")+empList1.get(i).get("1")+empList1.get(i).get("2")%></option>       
                                        </select>
                               <% }
                            }%> 
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="empRole">Employee Role:</label></td>

                            <td>
                            <select name="empRole" id="empRole">
                            <option value="" > Select Employee Role</option>
                                <%
                                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> roles = UserJdbcGenericDao.empDetails_AA();
                                for (int i=0;i<roles.size();i++) {%>                                        
                                <option value="<%=roles.get(i).get("0")%>"><%=roles.get(i).get("0")%></option>
                            <% }%>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>                    
                        <tfoot>                         
                            <tr>                                
                                <td colspan="5" class="table-footer">                   
                                    <input type="submit" class="button round green text-upper"  value="save"  onClick="return userValidate()"/> 
                                    <input type="reset" class="button round green text-upper"  value="Cancel" onClick="pageCall()"/>
                                    <!--<a href="usermanagementAddt.jsp" class="button green text-upper">cancel</a> -->


                                </td>                                   
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>                                
                    </table>
```

controller works like this if action ="insert"  then it goes to this condition and performs action :

```
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
    {           
        System.out.println("inside insert service");
        UserManager user = new UserManager();



        System.out.println("Emp_Num value:"+request.getParameter("empNum"));
        user.setEmpNum(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("empNum")));  

        System.out.println("Employee Name value is :"+request.getParameter("empName"));
        String empName=request.getParameter("empName");

        user.setEmpRole(request.getParameter("empRole"));
        System.out.println("Role value is :"+request.getParameter("empRole"));

        Boolean isAdd=dao.addUser(user);
        System.out.println("checking condition Value :"+isAdd);
        if(isAdd){
             System.out.println("Emp_Num value is :"+request.getParameter("empNum"));
             String emp_num=request.getParameter("empNum");
             String lastModifiedBy=hs.getAttribute("fullname").toString();
             hs.setAttribute("emp_num",emp_num);

             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList =com.compass.banker.dao.jdbc.UserJdbcGenericDao.empuid(emp_num);

             int indexs = 0;
             for (int j=0;j<itemList.size();j++) {
userId=itemList.get(j).get("0");
System.out.println("your creating UserId is:"+userId);
MessageUser users = new MessageUser();
String LastModifiedBy=hs.getAttribute("fullname").toString();
                    System.out.println("lastModifiedBy :"+LastModifiedBy);

                    System.out.println("login User id:"+LastModifiedBy);
                    users.setLastModifiedBy(LastModifiedBy);

                    users.setUserId(userId);


                    String mText="Hi"+userId+"Your Account has been created by "+LastModifiedBy+"in Compass data base";

                     users.setmText(mText);
                     System.out.println("Message Text value is :"+mText);

                     Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
                        String s = formatter.format(new Date());
                        System.out.println("Todays date is:"+s);
                        users.setLast_modified_date(s);




                    Boolean isAdded=dao.addUsers(users);

                    System.out.println("checking condition is:"+isAdded);

             }

             //Accessing the Email-Id to Send a confirmation Mail

             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList =com.compass.banker.dao.jdbc.UserJdbcGenericDao.empMail(emp_num);

             int index = 0;

             for (int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++) {
                    eMail_id=itemsList.get(i).get("0");                     

                    setMailServerProperties();

                    String msg="This mail is from Pinovus Consulting Pvt Ltd<b>";

                    try {
                        createEmailMessage(eMail_id,msg);
                    } catch (AddressException e) {
                        System.out.println("Mailing Address is not correct in createMailMessage...."+e.getMessage());
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        System.out.println("Message not send...."+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    try {
                        sendEmail();
                    } catch (AddressException e) {

                        System.out.println("Mailing Address is not correct in sendEmail...."+e.getMessage());
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        System.out.println("Mail not send...."+e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
            //System.out.println("2.you have to send a confirmation mail to this mail_id:"+eMail_id[i]);   

             String var="One User Account added successfully";

             RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/App_Admin/UsermanagementA.jsp?ref="+var);
               rd.forward(request, response);

            }else{
                System.out.println("Record not updated");
                response.sendRedirect("/App_Admin/statusMessage.jsp");
             }    

                    }
```

All these pages are there which are there in the code. But how to perform this alert or routing to another page if there is any database error as mentioned. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom error pages that Tomcat will server instead of 500's (or whatever): [Custom Error Page in Tomcat 7 for Error Code 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987212/custom-error-page-in-tomcat-7-for-error-code-500).

You could also do proper exception handling and generate error output as needed, specific to the current situation.

You can also create a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) that grabs unhandled exceptions and displays them appropriately.

You can also check for an existing entry first and don't attempt to insert if it exists (but be prepared to handle errors anyways in the case of race conditions in multi-user applications).

Comment: Hi Jason, I have tried that custom Error page in tomcat. But here my question is when there is any database connection problem or any query  not getting inserted then i need error page which is thrown from servlet or jsp

Comment: @Pallavipradeep Right. So what's wrong with all the other options I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you need show the error as alert, then you can use javascript `alert()`.
You can try `alert(<%=msg%>)`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i need only when record is not getting inserted through database

Comment: Means, you fail to insert data into database and returning the error message to your jsp and show that same message using alert.For that you may take the help of ajax, without page refresh you can do this.

Comment: ya while inserting a record into specific table that record is already there in the database and throwing unique key constraint violated. Now while executing application in browser it is showing errors instead i need an alert or a page that shows record not inserted

Comment: Yes, I understand but how you will do this because your page is refreshing on button click.On that case you can use ajax or jquery to insert the data where the page will not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are talking about the runtime exceptions that are thrown ,

For example ,  **ora00232 Invalid identifiers**

you can pass this objects in the response or set in the session,

In your code ,

```
catch(Exception ex)
   {       
              request.setAttribute("error",ex);    
   }
```

*//Forward your response*

Hope this helps !!

Comment: am using piece of code in DAO with jdbctemplate like this "JdbcTemplate jt=new DbConnection().getJdbctemplate();
   String sql="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ROLE(EMP_NUM,ROLE,STATUS)VALUES (?,?,'LOGGEDIN')";
   jt.update(sql,new Object[] { empNum,empRole});" here it is executing that jt.update directly now i would like to handle it. so suggest it.