# Tomcat is not redirecting to 400 bad request custom error page

Tags: tomcat, redirect, bad-request, tomcat9

We have tomcat 9 web server in production. The problem we are facing is we want to show the custom error page for our application if tomcat receives any malformed URL as follows

http://URL/|

or

http://URL/[

I  have added  error page tag in web.xml of tomcat application server as follows

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
```

and we have error.html in our application ROOT folder in webapps directory of tomcat.

Whenever the user tries to request any nonexistent webpage he receives error page correctly corresponding to 404 error code as specified above.

Real Problem is tomcat not able to redirect to error.html when the user enters malformed URL in the browser like http://URL/|

Tomcat is showing the default 400 bad request error page instead of the custom error page.

Comment: We are having the same exact issue. Did you eventually resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Still not able to resolve @stepanian

Comment: It looks like it's a bug rather than something we are doing wrong. We should probably notify the Tomcat development team.

Comment: This issue exists with tomcat 9 only. It works only fine with tomcat7 and tomcat8 @stepanian

Comment: Yes. It worked in Tomcat 8 for me too. It looks like it's a bug introduced in Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 25):

This is not a bug, it is a configuration issue.

Tomcat 9 has improved the error handling so that more errors, particularly those those occur before request processing starts, are passed to the standard error handling mechanism rather than just returning an error code.

In the case of malformed URIs, it is not possible for Tomcat to parse the URI hence the URI cannot be mapped to a web application. Tomcat is, therefore, unable to trigger the application level error handling because it cannot identify an application. In this case, the error is handled by the [ErrorReportValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve) which can be configured in server.xml.

A recent(ish) addition to the ErrorReportValve is the ability to define static web pages (i.e. no Servlets or JSPs, just HTML) per status code and/or Exception type in a similar manner to the per web application error page configuration.

Example Error Report Valve:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
        errorCode.400="webapps/ROOT/error400.html"
        errorCode.0="webapps/ROOT/errorOthers.html"
        showReport="false"
        showServerInfo="false" />
```

Comment: I can't seem to find any examples in the Tomcat documentation or anywhere else of how to configure the ErrorReportValve to return pre-defined static HTML pages.  Can you point me to any examples?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve

Comment: Yes, now implemented it for Tomcat 9.0.53 and it works. Ta. I suggest paying attention to special value of `errorCode.0`. That way you can centrally secure the whole server if it has many contexts.

Comment: This also works in [Tomcat 8.5](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve).

Comment: @Paul Uszak ,  this answer is not working for me though I have the customhtml file for error 400 at the location mentioned in your answer. Only the default tomcat error page for 400 keeps popping up. I want my custom400error.html to get rendered at screen. Help on this

Comment: @MdBasha Hiya. Just confirmed that it's showing my own 404 error page for all 400 errors.  Do you have the valve in server.xml? That's where it has to go (not web.xml). You can force your own 400 errors by GETting www.home.com/%foo.

Comment: @MdBasha I have "        <!-- This valve stops code 400 errors returning Tomcat info -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
               errorCode.0="webapps/ROOT/404.html"
               showReport="false"
               showServerInfo="false" />
"

Comment: No I am using this in server.xml only from the start but the line errorCode.400 is not referring to the path mentioned  and displaying the html as expected. Tomcat’s default is popping up every time.  Could please explain your line ‘ force your own 400 errors by GETting www.home.com/%foo’ ?

Comment: @Matt I am also using Tomcat 8.5.42 please give me the configuration For errorCode.400

Comment: @PaulUszak please confirm your production tomcat version?

Comment: @MdBasha Still 9.0.53 @ www.reallyreallyrandom.com. But to all out there, it's a fully patched system.

Comment: @MdBasha `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" errorCode.400="webapps/ROOT/server_error.html"/>` (note no errorCode.0 entry)

Comment: @MdBasha As Matt mentioned, ```errorCode.nnn``` also works for Tomcat 8.5, but it only works for specifically 8.5.*78* and after. See changelog: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html and related bugzilla: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41007 (it was backported from 9.0.6 according to the Author there)

Answer (score 9):

Below is sample configuration that follows https://stackoverflow.com/a/55702749/2532710 to save someone else time. 
In server.xml inside Host tag:

```
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
        errorCode.400="webapps/ROOT/error400.html"
        errorCode.0="webapps/ROOT/errorOthers.html"
        showReport="false"
        showServerInfo="false" />
```

Put static html error400.html ... errorOthers.html in webapps/ROOT of CATALINA_BASE.

Comment: Where is CATALINA_BASE?

Comment: @CodificadorD - If you did not define it, it is defaulted to CATALINA_HOME

Comment: @kosolapyj this is not working for me though I have the html file at the location mentioned in your answer. Only the default error page for 400 keeps popping up. I want my custom400error.html to get rendered at screen. Help on this

Answer (score 2):

Previous solutions were not working in my case.

According to the Tomcat doc, the valve component can put be into the container Engine, Host, or Context.
Tried everything without success regarding this specific error 400 (while others errors are handled as expected).

Finally I found the missing element in that enigma:

To be efficient, oddly enough, the Error Report Valve has to be put in the host container defined as the **defaultHost** of the catalina engine, even if it is not the targeted host.

server.xml example:
handle error 400 Bad requests for "some-cats.com" and "some-dogs.com" as well

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.some-dogs.com">
    <!--     NO EFFECT ON ERROR PAGE 400
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" /> 
    -->
    <Host name="www.some-cats.com">      
        <!--     NO EFFECT ON ERROR PAGE 400
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" /> 
        -->
        ...
    </Host>
    <Host name="www.some-dogs.com">
        <!--  HERE IS THE RIGHT PLACE FOR ERROR PAGE 400-->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" errorCode.0="path/error.html" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" />
        ...
    </Host>
</Engine>
```

Tested on tomcat 8.5.84 and 9.0.70

Of course if you just have one host, you don't have this problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved my case with multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own error page 
https://aspiresoftware.in/blog/catalinatomcat-custom-error-report-valve-to-handle-errors-exceptions/

You have to put your jar in tomcat lib.

Comment: this is not working for me though I have the html file and jar file at the location mentioned in your answer. Only the default error page for 400 keeps popping up. I want my custom400error.html to get rendered at screen. Help on this