# Exposed server details when invoking API with restricted characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We are using tomcat server on which Spring Boot Application is deployed.

When calling the API with requestParams as \

Output is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        b {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }

        p {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            color: black;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        a.name {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and
        RFC 3986</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a
        client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
    </p>
    <p><b>Exception</b></p>
    <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:483)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:682)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
</pre>
    <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.46</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

So, the problem is that this exposing the exception handlers and server details.
I want to hide all these details
Is there any setting in tomcat?

Hide the Server Details and stack trace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to build server level custom error page in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914575/how-to-build-server-level-custom-error-page-in-tomcat), or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/254102/custom-error-pages-on-apache-tomcat)

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876896/3018285)